# to use procedures from a class, when is the best time to extend a class vs. create an instance of that class?

Tags: java

In Java, I created a class `CommonExcelFunctions` to store procedures I use across a couple projects.  there are no abstract procedures in the class.  To use these, I'm trying to decide if I should make my other projects extend this class, or if I should instantiate it and access them all through the instantiated object.  which way makes the most sense?

Comment: If you can, sounds like a good case to make these `static`, but it's hard to give advice without seeing the actual use case for these functions or how they're implemented.

Comment: Maybe you can show us some of the `CommonExcelFunctions` you created.

Comment: yes, after reading other answers, static is what I'm going for.  is there a way to avoid typing the class name every time?  
so instead of  
int s = CommonExcelFuntions.GetLastRowNum();  
I can put:  
int s = GetLastRowNum();  
?

Answer (score 4):

Never ever use inheritance just for the sake of code reuse. The subclass relationship should be a meaningful *is-a* relationship, especially in a language like Java where you have only single-inheritance.

For such utility functions you describe static would probably best. Otherwise, use composition, i.e. create a member.

Comment: thank you, that's what I was wanting to know.  follow-up question, if I'm using it as a static, is there a way I can avoid having to type the class name every time I need to use a function?  can I make it so I can use:

FindLastRow();

instead of:

CommonExcelFunctions.FindLastRow();

Comment: Yes, see [static import](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) but that should be used very carefully as it leads to pollution of the local namespace, i.e. you might run into ambitious names.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what @AlexisKing mentioned, I often will create a utility class (such as `ExcelFunctionsUtil` and create a bunch of `static` methods in there. This is nice when the code is to be reused in multiple places, but inheritance doesn't make sense. I think inheritance only makes sense if the sub-class could actually be considered an extension or child type of the parent class. For instance, if you created an `UncommonExcelFunctions` class, that would seem to be an appropriate child of `CommonExcelFunctions`, but an `Accounting` class would not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Normally when in doubt, we ask ourselves the basics. Are we having a `is-a` relationship or `has-a` relationship.

If your new classes is indeed having an `is-a` relationship with your `CommonExcelFunction` class, then you probably can extends it.

So that answers your first question - **best time to extend a class**.

Else if it acts like a utility class, and some examples like those provided in Java (**Example**: `Math.max`, `Math.min`). You can implement your methods in the class as **static** (No instantiation required for usage of method).

**Think about this:**

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);  //Scanner class using instance methods
Math.max() //Math class using static methods
```

Why would Java want to implement the methods in Scanner as **non-static** while in `Math class` as **static**? You probably know the answer if you spend some time to think about it.

It is not necessary if you have some methods that we want to use directly for example (get the exponent of a number, get the max of 2 numbers,  rounding off a value..etc).

However it makes more sense to create instance methods (E.g. `Scanner class`) when we may need more than one type of scanner (**Example**: scanning console input, scan from file).

Answer (score 0):

You should **always** prefer composition to inheritance.
Your new class is not a 'CommonExcelFunctions' it just uses functions from CommonExcelFunctions.
You probably will not call functions from CommonExcelFunctions on instances of your new class. There's no need to pollute interface of your new class with methods from CommonExcelFunctions. It would break encapsulation.

When you use composition you can easily tests classes that use CommonExcelFunctions passing a mock.

When you use inheritance it's very difficult to test your class (partial mocks suck).

For example [go language](http://golang.org/doc/faq#inheritance) does not support inheritance at all.

See Effective java, item 16 "Favor composition over inheritance".

Comment: I don't think 'always' is appropriate.  Most of the times, yes, but not always.

Comment: I said "always prefer" not "always use" :P